# List tables only show sqlite_sequence

Tags: ios, sqlite

I'm running an iOS program in the simulator and I'm getting this error

> 'ISDatabaseSQLiteException', reason: 'failed to execute statement: 'create table GroceryItem(primaryKey integer primary key autoincrement, name text NOT NULL, number integer NOT NULL)' with mesage: table GroceryItem already exists'

This is the code that I'm using, in my AppDelegate.m

```
self.database = [[[ISDatabase alloc] initWithFileName:@"db20121207.sqlite"] autorelease];

if(![[database tableNames] containsObject:@"GroceryItem"])
{        
    [database executeSql:@"create table GroceryItem(primaryKey integer primary key autoincrement, name text NOT NULL, number integer NOT NULL)"];    
    [database executeSql:@"insert into GroceryItem (name, number) values('apple', 5)"];    
    [database executeSql:@"insert into GroceryItem (name, number) values('zuoyou', 3)"];
}
else
{
    [database executeSql:@"insert into GroceryItem (name, number) values('apple', 5)"];
    [database executeSql:@"insert into GroceryItem (name, number) values('zuoyou', 3)"];
}
```

I have this methods to list table names in `sqlite_master`

```
- (NSArray *) tables
{
    return [self executeSql:@"select * from sqlite_master where type = 'table'"];
}

- (NSArray *) tableNames
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [[self tables] valueForKey:@"name"]  );
    NSLog(@"%u", [[[self tables] valueForKey:@"name"] count]  );
    return [[self tables] valueForKey:@"name"];
}
```

but the console shows

GroceryList[7439:c07] (
    "sqlite_sequence"
)

2012-12-10 16:59:40.305 GroceryList[7439:c07] 1

only get the table `sqlite_sequence` and the count is 1; from the exception above, it said *"table GroceryItem already exists"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is related to `executeSql` method.

From this code `[[self tables] valueForKey:@"name"]` it seems that you are adding the table names to a NSDictionary object.

**Remember all keys in `NSDictionary` is unique**. You are adding all table names to the disctionary using `name` as `key`.

So it'll overwrite the previously added value. That's why it is showing a single element.

**Solution:**

1. Use different keys for different table names
2. Use `NSMutableArray` instead of `NSDictionary`
3. Change your table creating code like:

   `[database executeSql:@"create table if not exists GroceryItem(primaryKey integer primary key autoincrement, name text NOT NULL, number integer NOT NULL)"];`

There will be no need of that if...else condition